# 'NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType'

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an application that was running just fine under OS3+. But it does not work under OS4. I get the following error message:

> 'NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and
>   fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType'

Does it ring a bell to anyone here?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:myEntity];

    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch :[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FIELD1",@"FIELD2",@"FIELD3",@"FIELD4",@"FIELD5",nil]];      

    // Setting unique values        
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];       

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *initialDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"FIELD1" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:initialDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];      

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".       
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"FIELD1" cacheName:@"myCache"];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [initialDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];      

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I set [fetchRequest setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType] rather than [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType], my app loads normally.
`
BUT [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES] does not work anymore and I end up with duplicates!!!!

Help required please. :-)

Answer (score 15):

The error is referring to the fact that you are trying to obtain `NSDictionary` results, but then also expecting the fetched results controller to watch for changes. Since changes will only propagate through `NSManagedObjects`, the fetched results controller can no longer perform its job.

Using `NSManagedObjectResultType` does not work because then [setPropertiesToFetch:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW25) is no longer applicable. Instead, you would have to perform some coalescing of your own after the result set is known, which will make use with a fetched results controller rather difficult.

The best answer is to not set a cache name or a delegate for the fetched results controller, in which case it will [not perform any change tracking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1).