# Fetching all Core Data subentities

Tags: objective-c, sql, cocoa, core-data

Suppose I have a Song entity and Genre entity in Core Data. Genres have many Songs.

I want to perform a fetch request to fetch all songs' genres. This implies genres would show up multiple times. Or, in SQL terms,

```
select G.*
  from Songs S
       join Genres G on G.id = S.genre_id
```

I realise the SQL equivalent is a bit of a stretch since I don't need foreign/primary keys. The goal is the same. It seems simple, but I couldn't find an answer in my research that quite fit my problem.

My ultimate goal is to aggregate genres and count them, [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842113/260460). Again, in SQL terms:

```
select G.name, count(*)
  from Songs S
       join Genres G on G.id = S.genre_id
 group by G.name
```

I'm hoping that with the understanding from this question, I can add the code from the link to get what I want. Feel free to tell me it won't work if CD just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in your core data model each Genre has a to-many relationship with a Song, the following will give you a count of songs for each genre (which is actually aggregating your genres and counting them), where the genre is attached to at least 1 song:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY songs != NULL"];
NSEntityDescription *genres = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Genre" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:genres];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *genresArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"Total number of genres that have songs: %d", genresArray.count);
for (NSManagedObject *genre in genresArray) {
  NSLog(@"Genre: %@ (%@)", [genre valueForKey:@"genreName"], [genre valueForKeyPath:@"songs.@count"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an NSFetchRequest for the "Genre" entity with no NSPredicate? You'll get all Genre instances. Or do you want only genres that have songs? If so, you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785844/how-to-fetch-distinct-values-in-core-data).

Comment: Nope. What you propose will give me exactly one of every Genre. By querying Songs but selecting Genres, each Genre shows up once *per use*.