# GroupBy using @FetchRequest in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view like :

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Message(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Message.date, ascending: false)]
) var allMessages: FetchedResults< Message.date >

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(self.allMessages) { message in
            Text(message.text)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Last Messages"))
    }
}
```

I would like the FetchRequest to return only last message of each user. I need to use a group by. Is there a way using `@FetchRequest` ? If not, how would you do ?

Comment: What does your user entity look like? Do you have relationships established? If so, then you can simply fetch all of your users and populate the list with the last message in the list.

Comment: @Ludovic, were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Looks most solutions I found manually group this using `Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`. Doesn't seem like the most efficient solution to me.

Answer (score -1):

Step by step:

1. Create NSFetchRequest
2. Specify an NSPredicate to filter
   according to your chosen criteria
3. Set the resultType to ".DictionaryResultType" (required for "Group By")
4. Set the properties to be included in the fetch.
5. Set the properties to group by
6. Create an NSSortDescriptor to order by name, descending
7. Finally you can create @FetchRequest using the initializer "@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ")

```
class TODOItem: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var notes: String?
}

extension TODOItem {
    static func allTODOItem() -> NSFetchRequest<TODOItem> {
        //1º
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<TODOItem>(entityName: "TODOItem")
        //2º
        //fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "", ...)
        //3º
        fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        //4º
        // To get computed props you can use NSExpression (for example the sum of something)
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name", "notes"]
        //5º
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
        //6º
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        return fetchRequest
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: TODOItem.allTODOItem()) var items: FetchedResults<TODOItem>

    var body: some View {
        Text("Home")
    }
}
```

Comment: No it will crash because NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType

Comment: I don't know how you are using the NSFetchedResultsController but I think that for this case you could be not to set a cache name or a delegate for the fetched results controller, in which case it will not perform any change tracking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245262/nsfetchedresultscontroller-does-not-support-both-change-tracking-and-fetch-requ